# Accessing private inner class type from non-member template function

Tags: c++, templates, private, inner-classes

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Outer {
    struct Inner {
        int num;    
    };

public:
 static Inner GetInner() {
    return Inner{-101};
}
};

// void func1(Outer::Inner inner) {  // [1] Does not compile as expected
//  cout << inner.num <<endl;
//}

template <typename Dummy>
void func2(Outer::Inner inner, Dummy = Dummy()) {
    cout << inner.num << endl;
}


int main() {
    // func1(Outer::GetInner()); // [2] does not compile as expected 
    func2<int>(Outer::GetInner()); // [3] How does this compile? 
                                   // Outer::Inner should not be accessible
                                   // from outside Outer
    return 0;
}
```

How is it that I am able to use an argument of type `Outer::Inner`, which is a private type, in the non-member function `func2`? '`func1` rightfully complains when I try and use it with the following error message:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'void func1(Outer::Inner)':
prog.cpp:5:9: error: 'struct Outer::Inner' is private
  struct Inner {
         ^
prog.cpp:15:19: error: within this context
 void func1(Outer::Inner inner) {
               ^
```

I am using g++4.8.2 on ubuntu, but I also see this on gcc-4.9.2 (on www.ideone.com)

You can try out the code here: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/8303pB)

Comment: [clang reject it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba0a804da5d34cb9)

Comment: Looks like a g++ bug, did you find an answer meanwhile? To me, it shouldn't be legal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get

> Error 1   error C2248: 'Outer::Inner' : cannot access private struct declared in class 'Outer'

using Visual Studio 2013 update 4. Ergo, it is a problem in your compiler.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like clang has a problem with it.